# Foreach loop : duplicates output error

Tags: php, foreach

My code is as follows

```
$aNewCodes = array("93", "355", "213");
$aServiceProviderId = array();
$oTerminationRate = new TerminationRate();

foreach ($aNewCodes as $iNewCodesKey => $iNewCodesValue)
{
    $oTerminationRate->GetServiceProviders($aServiceProviderId, $iNewCodesValue);

    foreach($aServiceProviderId as $iProviderKey => $iProviderValue)
    {
        echo $iNewCodesValue." :: ".$iProviderValue."<br>";
    }
}
```

And it gives me output like this -

```
93 :: 1
93 :: 2
355 :: 1
355 :: 2
355 :: 1
355 :: 2
213 :: 1
213 :: 2
213 :: 1
213 :: 2
213 :: 1
213 :: 2
```

Actually I am expecting output like this -

```
93 :: 1
93 :: 2
355 :: 1
355 :: 2
213 :: 1
213 :: 2
```

Tried a lot to get that output, but no success. Where am I missing out ?

Comment: You are probably missing the part where `GetServiceProviders` accepts its first argument *by reference* and adds two items to it. If it did not, your code would not give *any* output.

Comment: yes, it accepts by reference, and the code does gives the output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not deleting previous entries from the `aServiceProviderId` array on each iteration of the loop.  Put line

```
$aServiceProviderId = array();
```

inside the first loop - right before

```
$oTerminationRate->GetServiceProviders($aServiceProviderId, $iNewCodesValue);
```

And you should be ok.

Comment: So, resetting the value of the one variable that is **not used anywhere** in this snippet will fix the problem?

Comment: `$oProviderForCountry = new ProviderForCountry();` is unnecessary in the code

Comment: @Jon Sorry, I copied/pasted a wrong line from the OP's code.  I now corrected it. You could have just edited the answer

Comment: @Sachyn I corrected my mistake in the code - wrong copy/paste

Comment: @AleksG: Removed the downvote, but this is still wrong and two wrongs do not make a right. `GetServiceProviders` is in obvious need of refactoring; slapping a band-aid on a broken design does not fix the design or prevent more problems in the future.

Comment: @Jon Agree, the design seems broken.  I simply pointed out where the problem is.  Regards.

Comment: @Jon Can you please tell what's wrong with the `function GetServiceProviders(&$aServiceProviderId, $iPhoneCountryCode) { }`. How do I improve it ?

Comment: Can't tell *what* is wrong without **much** more information, but it's easy to tell that *something* is wrong in the design.